# What it is the Best implementation for 3 Threads started by another one

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I need to implement this situation on Java:

I have 3 Threads for 3 different actions. Each action have to be executed in a different time. For example, action 1 it must run every 60min, action 2, have to be run every 40min and action 3 it must run every 120min.

Then, I have one Thread to call the other 3 Threads

What it is the Best implementation?

Use Timer?, Use Runnable?

Made a "While true" and inside do a GetTime and compare to know if I have to run some of the Thread?

Or maybe Sleep the Main Thread?

Thanks for the ideas and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Do the threads need to be run from within each other? Will they run indefinitely?

Comment: 'I have one Thread to call the other 3 Threads' - threads cannot be called - don't understand.

Comment: What have you tried?  Why don't you just have a single thread that will keep track of which threads need to be ran and when.

Comment: By the way: I found you English to be quite good.

Comment: @calderonmluis: yes, one thread call the other 3. It have to run forever. When one web system is loaded, the first thread it must be runned and this call the other 3. Each one with a different period of time

Comment: @Martin James run is a better way to say?

Comment: I will write a custom implementation for you during my lunch break if you still do not have an accepted answer.

Comment: @MarkComix, closed now sorry. Look into the Timer class, specifically the scheduleAtFixedRate() function. There are many things to consider specific to your implementation so I would do some more research into thread pools, synchronization, etc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Quartz API for that, http://quartz-scheduler.org/ this URL will help you.

Comment: I'm reading about this, Its looks good. Thanks

Comment: I'm working with this and looks really Good!. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have arguments for months on which is the best implementation.

Personally, I would be tempted to use something like a Timer and just have it repeated using the Timer API. I wouldn't even use a special thread if you just need a repeated task that runs forever. If you want to have a shut-off switch, you can have the timer run once and if the switch is still on, it could start another instance of itself.